# Creating multi directory on Desktop best practice

Tags: command-line

My pwd is

```
/home/john
```

and need to create three folders, `File1` `File2` `File3` in the Desktop folder. I have two choices.

```
cd Desktop/
mkdir File{1..3}
```

or

```
mkdir Desktop/File1 Desktop/File2 Desktop/File3
```

Is there a way to go with the second choice without having to type the relative path (Desktop) each time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
mkdir Desktop/File{1..3}
```

The above assumes that Desktop already exists.  If it doesn't, then use:

```
mkdir -p Desktop/File{1..3}
```